# How to run Office 365 applications as another user?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365

I have created a user (and set it is a part of `Administrators`and `Users`) with password using the `Computer Management` program.

When I try to run an Office 365 application as that user via clicking Run as another user and entering the correct username and password, I get this error message:

[image]

> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

I am only able to run Office 365 applications as that user when I am logged in into that user's Windows account.

What exactly is stopping me from running Office 365 applications as another user and how do I overcome it, if possible?

Comment: Are you able to run other application with that account, e.g. notepad? Maybe try to login with that account first.

Comment: @JosefBláha yes, I am able to run other application with that account

Comment: Make sure this user account is also assigned the license to Office365. In addition, have you ever uninstalled office?

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT I have never uninstalled office. Btw, can you explain why this user account needs to be assigned the license? I can't see how it could help because if this user account does not have permission to run Office apps, then I should also face the same error if I try to run them while logged in to that user account, right?

Comment: Run in PowerShell the command `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin`. Does it return anything?

Comment: @harrymc yes it does. Do you want to see the information it produced?

Comment: Yes, it might help.